# Amplify AppSync Codegen Error - invalid WIN32 path characters

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync, expo-router

`amplify push` after adding an api or running `npx @aws-amplify/cli codegen` produces

```
× Downloading schema failed
C:\Users\Renz\Desktop\Renz\Programming\Projects\random-chat-app\C:\Users\Renz\Desktop\Renz\Programming\Projects\random-chat-app\graphql contains invalid WIN32 path characters.
```

Fetching mutations or creating queries has been impossible due to this. I'm using expo-router if that matters

.graphqlconfig.yml - showcasing this file incase it is relevant

```
projects:
  randomchatapp:
    schemaPath: >-
      C:/Users/Renz/Desktop/Renz/Programming/Projects/random-chat-app/graphql/schema.json
    includes:
      - src/graphql/**/*.ts
    excludes:
      - ./amplify/**
    extensions:
      amplify:
        codeGenTarget: typescript
        generatedFileName: src/API.ts
        docsFilePath: src/graphql
extensions:
  amplify:
    version: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit .graphqlconfig.yml into

```
projects:
  randomchatapp:
    schemaPath: >-
      ./graphql/schema.json
    includes:
      - src/graphql/**/*.ts
    excludes:
      - ./amplify/**
    extensions:
      amplify:
        codeGenTarget: typescript
        generatedFileName: ./API.ts
        docsFilePath: ./graphql
extensions:
  amplify:
    version: 3
```